# save jsondata to plist by "key":"value" format

Tags: ios, plist

Here i have get data and convert it in to nsdictionary and use plist to store. I also put some NSLog to check whether my data have stored or not.but when i read my plist that i have store json .in my console its saying Null.

```
code is edited
```

So here is my code.Does any thing i am missing or any other way like "Key"-"Value" format to store my json data to plist.

Your help will move to next feature .Thanks in advance.

If any other method are available with "Key"/"value"- kindly let me know in code.Because i am new to ios & not well in code

This is my Json. Also please see here it having 4 category .In each category it having some id,data,date..

Log output:

```
plistPath : /Users/maicr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/144C1221-F589-415C-8855-3E5AA06459F8/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F405C7F-43F4-4910-B2CF-15083345F38C/Documents/SampleData.plist
2015-11-03 01:54:12.156 demo[10450:550543] Data successfully saved.
2015-11-03 01:54:12.157 demo[10450:550543] str: (null)
```

Comment: Please show the log output.  Also why are you writing a dictionary and reading an array? Also Also you can write directly to file using `[jsonResults writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];` rather than converting it to `NSData` first (I am wary of you re-assigning `returnData`).

Comment: @trojanfoe i have updated my code

Comment: i am new to code..if possible please rewrite my code with your answer,so that i can learn some thing

Comment: if possible please update your answer in code. And cant understand what you says about re-assigning `returnData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote

> convert it in to nsdictionary and use plist to store

and also the JSON confirms that (it starts with a curly brace), it can't be an array.

Instead

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

write

```
NSDictionary *stringsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

PS: I recommend to completely use the URL related API

Comment: one more question to you....i my json i am having 4 category .in each category having some id,file,images......so when i see my plist through iphone.how it will look like( i.e my json data)

Comment: JSON is just text. The `NSJSONSerialization` class converts the dictionary / array structure into its Cocoa counterparts and the string / number values to String / Int / Float. The `NSPropertyListSerialization` class creates a property list from the dictionary / array with the appropriate XML header signature.

Comment: does plist is still preferred to store data like json  ??

Comment: Thanks for your solution ....if possible please give some solution for another post. where my friend struggle with code--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483940/section-name-number-of-data-present-and-not-able-to-display-all-section-data

Comment: It's a very convenient way as the JSON types are property list compliant.

Comment: Google PLIST types, you can't put images in JSON or plist. Use URL/Path reference for that

Comment: true, but thats not a very elegant solution to storing binary data.

Comment: @vadian   
if possible please try to give solution for my friend whoes new to ios  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483940/section-name-number-of-data-present-and-not-able-to-display-all-section-data

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and it works. Also better use of the NSErrors that you are not using. It also doesn't rely on the plist being already created..

```
NSString *returnData = @"{\"count\":3,\"most\":{\"count\":0,\"files\":[]},\"deleted\":{\"count\":0,\"files\":[]},\"original\":{\"count\":4,\"files\":[{\"created_time\":1431939838,\"last_modified_time\":1431939859,\"id\":8293015,\"name\":\"doc1.pdf\"},{\"created_time\":1431939845,\"last_modified_time\":1431939869,\"id\":8293017,\"name\":\"doc2.pdf\"},{\"created_time\":1431939854,\"last_modified_time\":1431939886,\"id\":8293019,\"name\":\"doc3.pdf\"},{\"created_time\":1431939872,\"last_modified_time\":1431939898,\"id\":8293023,\"name\":\"doc4.pdf\"}]},\"extra\":{\"count\":0,\"files\":[]}}";
NSData *data = [returnData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // Your data may start as NSData to begin with...

NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];

if(parseError != nil )
{
    NSLog(@"Parse Error: %@", parseError.userInfo);
}
else
{
    //Build plist path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSMutableDictionary *plistData = nil;
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        // Pull existing plist
        plistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    }
    else
    {
        // Create new plist
        plistData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }

    [plistData setObject:jsonResults forKey:@"myJSONData"];
    [plistData writeToFile:path atomically:TRUE];


    // .....

    // Retrieve Data..
    NSMutableDictionary *savedJSONResults = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if([[savedJSONResults allKeys] containsObject:@"myJSONData"])
    {
        NSDictionary *myJSONData = [savedJSONResults objectForKey:@"myJSONData"];
        NSLog(@"%@", myJSONData);
    }

}
```

Pull JSON from web source using AFNetworking API

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:@"www.someAPI.com/resource" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *JSONKeyValuePairs = (NSDictionary *)responseObject; // serialized JSON data for you to do stuff with...

    // Do PLIST saving stuff here...

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSAssert(false, @"I failed."); // do something better than asset for release build since they are not compiled in. EI handle failures gracefully somehow.
}
```

Comment: you code look well. Does your code will save my json response data as "key"/"value" format

Comment: and one more thing in your first line code `NSString *returnData = @"{}"` You pass the  json data..But i gave only for example. I have 50 files inside my json.How i will put all inside that `NSString *returnData= @"{}"`.------

Comment: Are you pulling the JSON from a web source or from files on disk or something? And yes, NSDictionaries are key:value pairs.

Comment: if possible please try to give solution for my friend whoes new to ios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483940/section-name-number-of-data-present-and-not-able-to-display-all-section-data

Comment: As @vadian said, you should use a network library to make the HTTP request and fetch the JSON. Look at AFNetworking its very easy to use and has plenty of examples. It will also perform the JSON serialization for you.

Comment: friend i did all to fetch data from my url using "GET" and i conver my Json to NSDictionary and also i shows up in table view....Only i need to save data to database......so from my above code--- @vadian said- i used NSarray instead of NSDictionary

Comment: And too i thought you code show some thing new like -come up with "key"/"value"

Comment: Ok, so the root is an array not a dictionary. So everything is pretty much the same just use [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] instead. The PLIST itself is key value store, so you will pull out your array via the myJSONData key.

Comment: ok friend,Thnaks for your help...And please look up that link i provide above to solve that question problem